# Getting 3D slide direction

Tags: physics, vector, splines

I am trying to make my player slide down a curve (like a water slide) and so far I’ve managed to get the slide direction using the following code

```
float distance = point.Dot(planeNormal);
return point - distance * planeNormal;
/////
var slideDirection = MainUtils.ProjectOnPlane(Vector3.Down, Core.GetFloorNormal());
```

This works, but the problem is that sometimes the slide surface tilts. I don’t know if that’s the right word for it, but I hope the image below helps.
[image]

So, how do I maintain the desired sliding direction (the green line) even in this cases, ignoring the orange directions?

Comment: Very basic breakdown... The object's momentum will make it move along the green line (if its velocity is already along the start of the green line). The orange lines are the direction of  forces that will make the object follow the green line (assuming no additional forces are to be added).

Comment: My bad I gave that image as an example, I tried to make my problem as visible as possible, but the thing is that I have different slopes, with ups and downs, in any direction, that's why I would rather get the center line that goes across them (or a geodesic line, I guess?) so I can apply that as a velocity.

Comment: You say you want to "get the center line", but can you draw the center line (define it as a spine)?

Comment: Yeah, I made a spline that would mimic the shape of the slope, and tried to get the normal by subtracting the closest point on spline from the next one, but it does not really work. I think the way I get the closest Point is not working, but I'm still playing around with this. I'm open to any suggestions anyway.

Comment: Do you always want the object to follow your ideal path or do you need the path to be subjected to physics?

Comment: I want it to always follow the path and just be able to move away from it via input.

Comment: I think you need to drop the slide physics altogether, as trying to slide down a path while simultaneously ignoring the physics of it sliding off center greatly complicates the problem. Lock the object to the path and position it according to the normal of the spline in that location or possibly to the plane under the spline at that location.  Other method I can think of would be to put up invisible walls following the spline creating a sort of tunnel so that you can't slide outside of it. To move away from center, expand the width of the "tunnel".

Comment: I'll try and play around with the spline path some more and see what I can come up with. Thanks!